# Troubleshoot IE6 + 7 only error message

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have built the site: [www.bgarchitect.co.nz](http://www.bgarchitect.co.nz) which was as much a learning experience in jQuery and CSS/xHTML but is also a real project and as such should work in most browsers (IE6 is still a problem but IE7 should really not have an issue here).

Something that bugs me terribly is getting this error:
[IE6+7 Only Error PopUp http://www.9d.co.nz/screengrabs/ie_error.png](http://www.9d.co.nz/screengrabs/ie_error.png)

which only happens in IE 6 and 7. IE8 works fine, so does webkit and mozilla.

Simply put: I don't know where to look for "Line 8; Char 9" as the Source of the html only has a meta tag in line 8.

Since I have used a few jQuery/java-scripts I'm afraid it may be something in there, but the scripts DO work as they should even though i get this error pop up.

Any suggestions, ideas or solutions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks for reading and taking an interest.

Jannis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma somewhere in your javascript.

**EDIT**:
Here are the extra commas, inside `jsLinkNudging.js`:

```
$('.categories img').hover(function() { //mouse in  
    $(this).animate({ 
        marginTop: "5px", <- remove comma here
    }, "fast");  
}, function() { //mouse out  
    $(this).stop().animate({ 
        marginTop: "10px", <- remove comma here
    }, "fast");  
});
```

Look after both of the marginTop you have a comma but no more properties. Remove them both.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was indeed the problem.
I forgot to remove them after deleting the second property, that was there once upon a time.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced and uncheck the two boxes that say "Disable Script Debugging..."

Then when you get your error it will ask if you wish to debug, and then you say Yes, and it will launch Visual Studio and highlight the exact place where things have gone wrong.

You can get Visual Studio Express [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will uncheck them for future use! For now Paolo has already fixed the issue. Thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

you could also check this IE only add-on http://www.debugbar.com/
it behaves a lot like firebug and has a console too

Comment: thank you for your recommendation. I use firebug a lot so this should be an excellent addition to IE.